# Change 'shouldFix' parameter in ESLint

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I'm using ESLint with its VS Code extension to format my code.

At some point it stopped auto-formatting the code on save. I uninstalled everything and reinstalled anew: VS Code, ESLint and ESLint extension for VS Code.

I think I'm close to making the formatter work, but ESLint logs this in VS Code when I try and save a file with a linting error:

```
2020-10-10T10:41:45.345Z eslint:source-code-fixer shouldFix parameter was false, not attempting fixes
```

I guess if I find that `shouldFix` parameter and set it to `true` it'll work, but where is it?

Answer (score 7):

The above solution didn't work for me. I had to explicity add the following to my VSCode settings.

```
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    }
```

I think maybe something in the newest VSCode update communicating this with the plugin went wrong.

Comment: This is indeed the way to go - see [Version 2.0.4](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) section of eslint plugin docs. That version deprecated `autoFixOnSave` in favor of `codeActionsOnSave`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was the fix for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it changing the .eslintrc.js at the root of the project.

```
'parserOptions': {
    'ecmaVersion': 12,
}
```

instead of

```
'parserOptions': {
    'ecmaVersion': 2018,
}
```

I don't know why it worked till yesterday and then stopped.... but well that solved it for me.

Comment: This didn't work for me... you sure you didn't change anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Configuring a default formatter resolved this for me. From the [extension's page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint):

> eslint.format.enable (@since 2.0.0): uses ESlint as a formatter for files that are validated by ESLint. If enabled please ensure to disable other formatters if you want to make this the default. A good way to do so is to add the following setting "[javascript]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint" } for JavaScript. For TypeScript you need to add "[typescript]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint" }.

Answer (score -1):

run `npm run lint`
this will start debugging your code with eslint and your error should be solve then,

Comment: "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "lint": "eslint . --fix"
    },

Comment: The question is about VSCode not formatting on save, which is an automatic action. Your answer is completely unrelated to VSCode or to automatically fix linting errors, please read the question again